# thymeleaf 3 and th:field syntaxe

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a form template using thymeleaf 3 and I want to use `th:field="*{dueDate}"` syntax to bind my model property. I try to do the same as `th:value="${#strings.substring(model.dueDate, 0, 19)}"` but all my attempts fail.

It is possible to do this into a th:field instead of a th:value ?

EDIT:
I have to substring my date from java.sql.timestamp because it's a little bit different as the format used by my datepicker (2020-01-30 13:00:00.0 instead of 2020-01-30 13:00:00). I understand it isn't a good idea to substring the date string but It is difficult to have a entity method to bind the value as well with th:field. Probably I will use th:value in this case to give me the possibility to create that entity method providing the good format.

Comment: `th:field` is only for binding the fields of an object which you pass as Model attribute (Spring MVC) or context variable to/from your controller. There is no other way to acheive that except of the one you described with `th:value`. Could you please describe what you want to acheive exactly?

Comment: You can format the date in your entity class, by adding the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation to the field:
 `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

Second option is to format your date in the datepicker (most of them have such funcionality).

Comment: Thanks too. I thinks @DateTimeFormat is a good way for me :)